# Hovering over navigation link to show a separate div

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is have a link called 'Weather' in my navigation bar, and when you hover over it or click it, I want it to show a dropdown with the weather network widget inside of it.

This is what I have so far. The hover part works, however it pushes the 'weather' link to the bottom of my navigation bar. How do I get it to resume its original position?

```
    <div id="navbar"> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">Home <img src="home.png" /></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Forum <img src="forum.png" /></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Pictures <img src="camera.png" /></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Videos <img src="videos.png" /></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Technology <img src="technology.png" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Politics <img src="politics.png" /></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">World Issues <img src="issues.png" /></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Contact <img src="contact.png" /></a> 
            <li><a href="#"><div id="div1">Weather <img src="weather.png" /></a><div id="div2">testing</div></div></li> 
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#div1 {
    cursor:pointer;
 }
#div2 {
    display:none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 20;
 }
#div1:hover #div2 {
    display:block;
 }
```

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8CaE.png) of what it looks like.

Comment: I wonder if there is a disparity between the size of weather.png and the size of div2 - Maybe try div2 with no height and width to see what happens. Or give the .png a height and width in the <img tag

Comment: You should use nested li tags instead of showing and hiding a 2nd div.

Comment: Might not be enough room on your navbar for all the elements, and it is pushing the last one down to the next line. Try backing down your margin/padding, see what happens.

Comment: could you show us an example of what you want to happen on jsfiddle or something? It is a little unclear of the exact effect you want. It seems like you absolute positioning is breaking the flow of your document to me though.

Comment: Here is a live version of my sample website. Hover over weather http://xellic.wink.ws/index.html

Comment: The HTML for your "weather" list item is not consistent with the rest of your menu items. It looks like there may be a mistake there. If you clean up your HTML it will be easier to isolate the possible causes and test/fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should fix your HTML. Replace your divs line with this (I am reformatting it for the sake of the readability of my answer):

```
<li id="div1">
    <a href="#">Weather <img src="weather.png" /></a>
    <div id="div2">testing</div>
</li>
```

And then, try this CSS code:

```
#div1 {
    position: relative;
}
#div1 > a {
    cursor:pointer;
}
#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;

    display:none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 20;
 }
 #div1:hover #div2 {
    display:block;
 }
```

It works because when you place an absolute positioned element inside a relative positioned element, the absolute element will position itself according to the bounds of the relative element. Therefore, `top: 100%` will place `#div2`'s top at the bottom of `#div1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Javascript to detect click on weather link (add an id ou a class), and on click show in a popup (google a jquery plugin) the weather widget.

Comment: this doesn't seem accurate. Can you link to the source you are referencing?

Answer (score 0):

Your html is out of order.  While it will render, it won't render as you expect. Try this for the weather link:

```
<li><div id="div1"><a href="#">Weather <img src="weather.png" /></a><div id="div2">testing</div></div></li>
```

For an onclick event, you will need to use javascript or jquery:

```
$("#div1").on("click", function () {
    $("#div2").css("display", "block");
}
```

You can also put the onclick event in the  tag, if you want.